Goldbachs conjecture by contradiction
In the following Statement I am using the example of the even number $100$ to demonstrate a fact that would occur if there where no pair of primes that add up to $2n$ or here in this example $100$. This is no complete proof.
If you assume there is no pair of two odd primes that add up to $100$, then all $24$ under an hundred odd primes would need a non prime partner. So they would be exactly $24$ of pairs with one prime and $26$ where both numbers are non prime or composite.
So generally speaking, if you look at a sum of $2n$, you can determine the amount of non primes pairs by subtracting $n-p$ where $p$ are all odd primes up to $2n$.

From what I understand, under this assumption there should be $24$ pairs with one prime and one composite, and $1$ pair with both numbers being composite culminating to $25$. Generalising, this should be determined by $\frac{n-2p}{2}$, not $n-p$. Furthermore, https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Sorry for any confusion.  I meant 26 pairs of both non primes, because there 50 pairs and 24 with exactly 1 prime. So 50-24=26

3 + 97 = 11 + 89 = 17 + 83 = 29 + 71 = 41 + 59 = 47 + 53 = 100

I know that there are combinations of odd primes that add up to 100. I want to assume the opposite for a proof per contradiction. And 100 was just an example to highlight the more general expression  of how many non primes pairs there has to be under the assumption

You have less chance of proving (or refuting) Goldbach's Conjecture using school mathematics than you have of curing cancer using the contents of your refrigerator. Do something useful instead, like all the exercises in a good intro Number Theory textbook.

Consider $n=20$, so $2n=40$. The odd primes less than $2n$ are $$3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37$$ Hence, $p=11$. According to your generalization $n-p$, there will be $20-11=9$ non-prime pairs. However, there are $10$ non-prime pairs of $40$, being $$(4,36),(6,34),(8,32),(10,30),(12,28),(14,26),(15,25),(16,24),(18,22),(20,20)$$ This does not match up with $n-p$ and therefore the generalization is not correct.
I am not able to provide an accurate general formula for this case.

Alternatively, a simpler disproof can be seen with $n=2$, so $2n=4$. The only odd prime less than $2n$ is 3, so with $n-p$, there are $4-1=3$ non prime pairs. However, there are $0$ non-prime pairs of $4$.

Yes you are correct there are more pairs of both numbers being non primes than n-p which implies because of the pigeon hole principle that there are pairs where both are prime. But if assume there is no such pair of primes. Then  there must be exactly n-p pairs with composite numbers.

Is $p$ not defined as the number of all odd primes under $2n$? I don't understand what you mean by 'assume no such pair of primes' when primes are integral to the answer. Furthermore, only composite pairs are being used in the disproof. Sorry for the confusion but is it possible to provide a more comprehensive explanation. Feel free to reach out for any help!

@Olli: "if assume there is no such pair of primes [whose sum is $2n$] then there must be exactly n-p pairs with composite numbers" This is correct. However, that's quite an assumption, in light of Goldbach's Conjecture.

Hey Keixx, I will try to explain more accurately. I want to proof Goldbach statement which you probably know. If you assume there is no pair of primes that up to hundred then every of the 24 odd primes hast to have a non prime partner like 5 + 95. There are 50 pairs to consider. If all 24 odd primes need a composite partner then the rest of them have to be 26 pairs of composite  Numbers. If this doesn’t make sense. I will think about it thurther. I am not an native speaker so sorry for my mistakes

@blue yes this is also not a whole proof

@Olli: You should edit the question to state that your ultimate intention is to prove Goldbach, or at least make clear that you're aware your assumption violates it. (Note: The fact that $100$ doesn't fit your desired assumption makes your example a distraction. I recommend jumping right to stating the general case; eg, "If we assume $2n$ is not the sum of two primes (ie, if we deny Goldbach's conjecture), and if $p$ is the number of primes less than $2n$, then I claim $n-p$ is the number of pairs of (positive) non-primes whose sum is $2n$. [give argument] Is this correct?") ... Good luck!

@blue thx for pointing that out
